# Default link color still showing up, even after changing with CSS

Tags: css, colors

I have my nav and li with the links, and went in to change the color with my CSS.  Usually this works fine for me, but today I just can't seem to figure out the glitch.  The link for my nav is still showing up as the default color, not the color I set in CSS.

I tried cleaning up the code, and am still running into the problem.  What is odd is that the hover color is working fine, but the display color is not.

Here is the code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="index.html">home</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="about.html">about</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="photos.html">photos</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="contact.html">contact</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="prices.html">prices</a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```css
/*Nav*/
nav {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 45%;
  margin-right: auto;
}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #4C4C4C;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #f64751;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Did you clear your cache? Often a mistake made by novices. While your code isn't as pretty as you'd like, there's technically nothing wrong with it (though you could stand to brush up on best practices). Your links should be #4c4c4c.

Comment: ctrl F5 if you are on windows...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you reduce the CSS further until none can be removed while still running into the problem?

Comment: I updated my question with some cleaned up code.  Still no luck fixing the issue. I am on a mac - just FYI

Comment: Looks like [it's](http://jsfiddle.net/mfLbogyL/) working to me. Have you cleared your cache yet or tried a different browser?

Comment: I cleared my browser history, and tried opening it in both Chrome and Firefox.  The "home" link is still showing up as green in both browsers.

Comment: But have you cleared the cache? Also, is the fiddle working as expected for you?

Comment: What does the CSS look like in the dev tools--what is setting it green (right click > inspect element)? Are you by chance using some library that may be adding an 'active' class?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did clear the cache along with browser history.  I am not using fiddle, just testing locally on my browser. I am using only html and css, no js for this project.

Comment: by fiddle, he is referring to [http://jsfiddle.net/mfLbogyL/](http://jsfiddle.net/mfLbogyL/). What do the dev tools tell you?

Comment: Ted -  YES.  There was a hidden a:active a:visited css code in my template.  All is well now!  Thanks everyone!